# Are there Linux utilities for previewing files (partic. .doc's) rather than full-blown editing?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, documents, libreoffice, preview

Instead of opening .doc, .odt, etc. files in LibreOffice which is resource intensive, are there any good utilities for simply viewing (previewing) such files without the need for editing facilities? Thank you.

Comment: Google docs. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that [`antiword`](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) was designed for.

You can convert MSW documents into plain text, PDF, PostScript, and DocBook, depending on which reader you prefer to view files in.